# child_added is fired when removing element and twice when element is added

Tags: firebase

I would like to observe a subtree for child_added event. I have code defined like this:

```
usersRef.on('child_changed', (usersSnapshot) => {

    log.info('user changed!');

    usersSnapshot.ref().child('friendRequests').once('child_added', (friendRequestsSnapshot) => {

        log.info('friend request added!');

     }
 }
```

But I have problem with this approach. First of all when a new element is added to friendRequests, the callback is called twice. The second problem is that when I remove the element from friendRequests, the child_added callback is also called. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Sounds odd. But I must admit that `once('child_added'` is a *very* uncommon combination. Can you set up a jsfiddle/jsbin that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Sure, this is how it looks like: http://plnkr.co/edit/uoGJJL?p=catalogue

Comment: I meant something that **reproduces** the problem. Copying the code into a plunkr in a non-runnable form doesn't help. If you're worried about exposing your Firebase database URL, just create a temporary database that you delete afterwards.

Comment: Why are you doing a child_changed on usersRef and then child_added on a child or the usersRef? What are wanting the code to to do exactly?

Comment: friendRequests is an array of elements. I want fire a callback every time the new element is added to this array.